# Is there a way to directly access a MariaDB or MySQL table index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I've read somewhere in recent months that there was a project(s) that integrates with MySQL or MariaDB that allowed direct index access as a performance optimization.

Specifically, some kind of interface that would allow you to directly say things like:

- "give me the ID of the record where this indexed column matches BLAH" or
- "does an ID of this value exist in this specific index"

...and allows you to do this bypassing the SQL query parsing, planning, etc. steps, and thus gain higher throughput for speed-sensitive operations.

I can't seem to find this just Googling around for it.  Anyone familiar with projects doing this?  Just looking for links to anything open source that does this sort of thing. (Am specifically dealing with MySQL [or one of it's derivatives], but other open source projects might be relevant as well.)

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

I've ready on highscalability.com and other places of shops moving from a traditional RDBMS to a NoSQL-style solution (or deciding to go NoSQL at the start of a new project) only to later regret it and find that the advantages of NoSQL do not outweigh the drawbacks of having to build something around a storage platform that doesn't support the flexibility of SQL (basically: it's a pain in the neck to be writing joins by hand in code, rather than being able to easily query that stuff).  I could have sworn I'd read some things about people using "traditional" RDBMSes and then exposing the raw indexes directly for those specific cases where high performance was really needed, as a potential solution. But I don't see much on this when searching around.  Thus this question.

Comment: Why do you think `SELECT id FROM table WHERE col = 'value'` wouldn't satisfy you?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of [HandlerSocket in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/handlersocket/) or [HandlerSocket in Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/handlersocket.html) or the [InnoDB Memcached API in MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-setup.html). Realistically, though, you should not take using one of these solutions lightly. They are useful, perhaps, for a select number of applications and uses where the difference is both noticeable and beneficial and for most of the entire world you're just making your life more difficult and asking for strange bugs by using them. Tread carefully.

Comment: That looks like just the thing.  The scenario I'm thinking of is for a data warehouse of stat and other analytics information.  I need the flexibility of an RDBMS but at the same time I predict that for some performance critical queries I'll need that extra ability to have the query parser and wire protocol overhead just get out of my way as much as possible - in order to speed things up enough.  I'll have to test it out, but it seems like this could provide that alternate option - but as you say - only if warranted. Thanks for the links and I agree with the caution.

Comment: I think you may be surprised. MySQL is quite capable of tens of thousands of queries per second on a single machine if they are the simple type which could be done through HandlerSocket or Memcached interfaces.